# cmake file to include relative directory out of current directory

Tags: c++, cmake

my folder like

```
my_dir
   CMakeLists.txt
   my_cpp.cpp
common_utils
   common_util.h
   common_util.cpp
```

In my_dir/CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../common_utils)
```

In my_cpp.cpp I use

```
#include "common_util.h"
```

but I got compiling error for "no such file or directory" of "common_util.h".

How to solve the problem in `CMakeLists.txt`? Thanks.

Comment: after your `add_executable(targetName ...)` use `target_include_directories(targetName PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../common_utils)`

Comment: Relative paths are perfectly usable inside `include_directories`. The problem is *somewhere else* in your code.

Comment: Use `cmake --build build_dir --verbose` and check, if the include directory is properly mentioned in the compiler options of the step that fails. It probably isn't and you'll need to adjust the cmake file...